# Jordan measure of a curve

Tags: calculus, geometry, measure-theory, area, arc-length

I'm reading through the [Wikipedia article on Jordan measure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_measure) and I understand how one could use it to find the area or volume of a 2- or 3-dimensional region.  But how would one find the length of a plane curve or space curve?

In particular, the article says that you find the inner Jordan measure by taking the infimum of the collections of disjoint rectangles strictly contained in the region and similarly for the outer Jordan measure the supremum of the collections of disjoint rectangles that strictly contain the region.  Then your set is Jordan measureable if those two values are equal.  But a simple curve like a circular arc would neither be contained in any line segment (a 1-rectangle) nor contain any nondegenerate line segments.

So how can we use Jordan measure to find the length of a curve?  I'm fine with the regular calculus idea of approximating a curve by a bunch of line segments as in the image

[image]

but that doesn't seem to be the idea with Jordan measure (though I could certainly be misunderstanding).  Are "curved" sets simply not Jordan measureable?

Comment: Perhaps you should have been reading this Wikipedia article: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hausdorff_measure

Comment: I see.  Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Afaik, the jordan measure lets you measure $n$-dimensional objects in $\mathbb R^n$. If you tried to measure a surface in $\mathbb R^3$, you'd also end up with $0$. Which is one reason to use Hausdorff measures instead.

Comment: That's the conclusion I've come to as well.  Hausdorff measure just looks a lot more complicated right now.  But thanks for the info, you guys!

Comment: @Dylan You can measure curve in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ with $1-$dimensional Hausdorff measure which will give you the length of the curve. The same applies to surfaces in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ but $2-$dimensional Hausdorff measure might be not exactly equal to the surface area, but proprtional to it (I am not sure).